# How to disable auto join lines on save in VS code?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

While using VS code on typescript, every time I save the file it automatically joins the lines for me which is kind of annoying sometimes.

For exmaple,
it will auto format

```
export {
    A,
    B,
    C
};
```

to

```
export { A, B, C };
```

Does any one know how to disable it?
Note that I already have Editor: Format on Save unchecked in my settings.

Answer (score 2):

You can disable formatOnSave in vs code settings with `editor.formatOnSave: false`.
See https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings

Alternatively if prettier is the formatter configured you can disable prettier for a given node/line with `// prettier-ignore`.
See https://prettier.io/docs/en/ignore.html

Comment: I already have Format On Save unchecked in my setting. I also tryied to add `editor.formatOnSave: false` in my settings.json. Both didn't solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You may have Format On Save turned on. Go to the Text Editor > Formatting settings and uncheck if needed. If that doesn't help, have a dig around in there.

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings

Answer (score 0):

reduce the ***ColumnLimit*** field to zero in the settings.json file.

ColumnLimit: 0

Explanation:

A column limit of 0 means that there is no column limit. In this case, formatter will respect the input’s line breaking decisions within statements unless they contradict other rules.